# PetaPoco over multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-design, .net-4.0, petapoco

Don't ask why but there are four databases.  One of which I have rights to modify the schema. Let's call it **external**.  Again, it's a legacy deal but there are about 60 tables in one of the other three databases, called **main**.  Each record in those tables has a field that links it to a record in a corresponding table in **external**.

PetaPoco will make quick work of a lot of the trouble.  Tentatively, I've tried multiple Database.tt files to manipulate all four databases.  Is there a better way?

1. Should I create synonyms or views in **external** that refer to the goods in the other databases?  And then only use one Database.tt on **external**?
2. Is a combined POCO for the linked tables reasonable?

Comment: Synonyms do not provide column details.  So the multiple tt files are the only way to gen POCOs.  Multi-table views only insert on one of the base tables atomically.  I will, however, still create synonyms to allow cross database queries at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The Database.tt is only used to pre-generate some poco out of your schema. I can hardly believe you are going to leave it there without modification. Normally I would start there and change to make more reasonable linked (with property complex properties for linked tables)

As to linked table queries, as they must be executed in 1 query, thus you have to only keep connection to only 1 db, thus a linked table is necessary. But be ware of low performances. Cross database table joins can sometime be 10 times slower than local joins, depending on sqls. If you have nested select cross multiple db tables, better to make temp table to avoid performance issue.